# WP_Query shortcode output

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

i am trying to create shortcode but for some reason i have problem with the output,it should be inside < li > but it's outside

testPhoto 4Photo 3Photo then 3 li html tags

here is the code below:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

         if( $the_query->have_posts()): 

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();                       

            $output .= "<li>". the_title() . "</li>";                   

            endwhile; 

         endif; 

     wp_reset_query();               

    return $output;
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code, for context? You could try this:  

`the_title( '<li>', '</li>', false );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the_title() without parameters directly outputs the value. According to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) to receive the value pass 3 parameters:

```
the_title('', '', FALSE);
```

The first two are strings added before and after the value.

Comment: Thank you Kwebble, i am trying also to put the the_post_thumbnail inside < li > but it's not working :-(

Comment: For that there's a separate function, get_the_post_thumbnail http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail. It's common for WordPress having a the_... to output a value and get_... function to retrieve that value for further processing. See the docs.